# Go to a Console position in C++ (on OSX)

Tags: c++, macos, console-application

I have this piece of c++ code which works perfectly on Windows but I'm trying to port it to OSX and getting a lot of compilation errors.

Is there an equivalent library for OSX?

```
#include <windows.h>
void gotoXY(int x, int y)
{
     //Set the coordinates
     COORD coord = {x, y};
     //Set the position
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
     return;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the downvote. How is this not a legit question?

Comment: use ncurses: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ncurses.3x.html

Comment: I want to go to a specific location on the console. I dont see how the code is NOT self-explanatory enough. ALso, the question it self says "GO TO a console position ....". How is that not clear enough?

Comment: @Hyde So you basically close every question you don't have an answer to? Is this what SO has become? (Your excuse on "question not clear enough" is B.S)

Comment: I think the question is perfectly understandable, but SO isn't a resource for finding libraries. In this case there's pretty much one really common library, ncurses, but if there were a bunch then the answers would be a lot less useful. Not that ncurses is universal (there are alternatives), but it's probably by far the most common.

Comment: Well, to me, SO is where you ask a programming-related question. In my case, I honestly don't know where to look. First time hearing of this "ncurses" thing (yes, C++/osx novice here). So if someone points out to me ncurses is the place to go, i'd take it as a great answer!

Comment: @DanielH: Don't just close a question because it says "library". The ban is on recommendations. This question is sufficiently specific and does not ask for recommendations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use nCurses library (recommended), or use ANSI escape sequence:

```
// nCurses, you need to initialize the window before
move(x, y);
```

```
// ANSI escape seq
printf("\033[%d;%dm", x, y);
```

Comment: Thanks! the esc seq solution is brilliant! Should have thought of it

Comment: @OneTwoThree The escape sequence solution works, most of the time, as long as you really are on a terminal, and as long as the terminal isn't weird in some way. Using a library like ncurses is almost certainly better if this isn't throw-away code.

Comment: I've tried using `move()`, it doesn't work. giving an error saying "not supported with x86 64 architecture" ... I guess I should redefine the question to whether it's possible to implement such a `move(x,y)` function that it'll works on all platforms (if so, how?)

Comment: @OneTwoThree Use macros so your function compiles differently across platforms.